# Trying to share a contact group on iPhone?

Tags: sharing, group

On my laptop, using my iCloud account, I have created a Contact Group for my iPhone.

I'm trying to make it easy to send text announcements to the Football Team.

How do I share or export that Contact Group with another iPhone user?

Comment: Select all the contacts and drag them to finder. It will create a .vcf file you can send to others.

Comment: HI... is "FINDER" on a MAC -- I have an HP Laptop.
are you "selecting" all the contacts on icloud or on the iphone?

Comment: @FOOTBALL MOM Finder is on the Mac, so that solution doesn't apply to you.

Comment: Please don't use all caps. Sorry, by default I assume you have a Mac. If you have the contacts on your phone, you can just send them to others. If there are a lot (to many to send manually) then you'd have to figure something out. What are you using to sort your contacts on your computer?

Comment: icloud in Chrome....

Comment: How many contacts are there? Are there too many to send one by one?

Comment: @FOOTBALLMOM IronCraftMan means you go on your iPhone, and separately send all of the contacts in that group to someone.

Comment: there are 24 contacts -- you cannot send a group text (manually) with more than 10 contacts -- thus making the coach send 3 texts everytime --

by texting the entire team -- in one group -- it would alleviate al that,

Comment: Wait, are you trying to say you want to text everyone in that group, or send the group's information to other people?

Comment: I don't believe you can text a group. Why do you need to send the contacts out in the first place?

Comment: @IronCraftMan do you need a program? "Coach", "team", "FOOTBALL MOM".... Do you really need to ask why?  I get it... Unfortunate football mom, what you want doesn't exist yet.... Apple.con/feedback and suggest it

Comment: @Tyson I'm not asking why you want to send out the messages, just why you were asking to send out all of the contact cards.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work on Chrome for Mac, so it may be the same on Windows & require that you use a different browser to achieve it...

- Go to https://www.icloud.com/#contacts
- In the left column, select your required group
- Gear menu, bottom left -
  Select All, then
  Export vCard

[image]

The exported file contains all the contact details for that group of contacts.
This can be shared.

Whether that data can then be used to send a single text may be dependent on your carrier.